# Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation in line 25

Tags: pine-script

So for some extrange reason im getting this error Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation, does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Instead, copy&paste it here and use the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-iff-function) incorrectly.

The syntax is:

```
condition ? result1 : result2
```

You are missing the `:` and `result2`.

Comment: I just want 1 result, so like if the condition is false do something like null

Comment: @Zalcab Then write that as the last part of the ternary. The operator always takes two possible outputs.

Comment: Then you need to use `na` . So, `condition ? result1 : na`